# merge N sorted files using shell

Tags: shell

I have N files, the content within each file is sorted, and now I want to merge these N files using `sort -m`, it is a N-way merge.

But I have this problem, each of these N files is updating, which means the content within each file is the output of another program, the program writes the output into each file constantly.

For example, at this moment, the first file looks like this:

```
1
3
5
```

10 minutes later, it is updated by the program and looks like this:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
```

If the N files are not updating, I can simply use `sort -m`, but now how to do it?

To clarify, what I want in the end is that, all the content in N files should be merged into one final file, that means if those files are updated, the newly updated content should also be merged.

*UPDATE*

**Bash on Linux**, lines in each file is in monotonically ascending order, no duplicates between files.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are expecting in the end. You want the merged file to be updated as well?

Comment: Also, this will run on what operating system?

Comment: @RenatoZannon, I updated my post to clarify what I want in the end, and this will run on Linux.

Comment: Which shell are you using on which O/S? How large is N (roughly, is it more than 200…less than that doesn't matter).  Is the generated data guaranteed to be in monotonically ascending order in each file? Can there be repeats in a file?  Can there be repeats across files (so file.1 and file.2 both contain the value 37, for example)? How are you going to know when there are no more rows being written to any of the files?  Timeout? End marker?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is linux, you can rely on the `inotifywait` utility, from the `inotify-utils` package:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES_TO_WATCH=("file1.txt" "file2.txt")
MERGED_FILE="merged.txt"

log() {
  echo "[$(date -R)] $1" 1>&2
}

merge_files() {
  log "Updating merged file"
  sort -m "${FILES_TO_WATCH[@]}" > "$MERGED_FILE"
}

wait_for_changes() {
  local changed_file
  changed_file=$(inotifywait -qe modify "${FILES_TO_WATCH[@]}" --format "%w")

  log "File '$changed_file' changed"
}

merge_files

while wait_for_changes; do
  merge_files
done
```

Breakdown of the `inotifywait` command:

`-q`

Be quiet, as opposed to logging status messages to stderr.

`-e modify`

Listen for the "modify" event. For other events, see `man inotifywait`.

`--format "%w"`

Make it print only the filename when a modify event occurs.

`${FILES_TO_WATCH[@]}`

Expand the files on the `FILES_TO_WATCH` array.